# Understanding clang loop-optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

I've got this piece of code

```
#include  <cstdlib>
#include <time.h> 

int sum () {
  srand (time(NULL));
  unsigned long extra = rand() % 10; 
  int sum = 0;
  // #pragma nounroll. <<<< This makes no difference
  for (int i = 0; i < 16 + extra; ++i) {
    sum += i;
  }
    return sum;
}
```

and with `-O3`, clang optimized it to the following, which blew my mind. (Note how there's no branches whatsoever)

I really don't understand how the correctness of such optimization could be proved.
Specifically, the use of two seemingly magic numbers (which, btw, don't change between compiles) seems mystifying. Furthermore, I guess you call these "random" but not in spirit of the `rand()`, no?

```
sum():                                # @sum()
        push    rax
        xor     edi, edi
        call    time
        mov     edi, eax
        call    srand
        call    rand
        cdqe
        imul    rcx, rax, 1717986919. # <<<< magic number
        mov     rdx, rcx
        shr     rdx, 63
        sar     rcx, 34
        add     ecx, edx
        add     ecx, ecx
        lea     ecx, [rcx + 4*rcx]
        mov     edx, eax
        sub     edx, ecx
        neg     ecx
        add     eax, ecx
        add     eax, 16
        lea     rcx, [rax - 1]
        movabs  rsi, 8589934590 # <<< magic number
        add     rsi, rax
        imul    rsi, rcx
        shr     rsi
        lea     eax, [rsi + rdx]
        add     eax, 15
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

For posterity, gcc produced the following

```
sum():
        sub     rsp, 8
        xor     edi, edi
        call    time
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    srand
        call    rand
        mov     esi, 1
        movsx   rdx, eax
        mov     ecx, eax
        imul    rdx, rdx, 1717986919
        sar     ecx, 31
        sar     rdx, 34
        sub     edx, ecx
        lea     ecx, [rdx+rdx*4]
        add     ecx, ecx
        sub     eax, ecx
        mov     edx, eax
        add     eax, 16
        movsx   rcx, eax
        cmp     edx, -16
        cmovne  rsi, rcx
        cmp     eax, 18
        jbe     .L6
        mov     rdx, rsi
        movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        xor     eax, eax
        movdqa  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        shr     rdx, 2
.L3:
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm1
        add     eax, 1
        paddd   xmm1, xmm3
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     eax, edx
        jne     .L3
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        mov     rdi, rsi
        psrldq  xmm1, 8
        and     rdi, -4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movsx   rdx, edi
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm1, 4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movd    eax, xmm0
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        je      .L1
.L5:
        add     eax, edx
        add     rdx, 1
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        ja      .L5
.L1:
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L6:
        xor     edx, edx
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L5
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
.LC1:
        .long   4
        .long   4
        .long   4
        .long   4
```

Comment: There's one problem: it seems the example code is *C++*

Comment: Probably replaced the loop with `res = (16+extra-1) * (16+extra-2) / 2`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Sorry, I was a bit overzealous in tag editing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It does not change the result. Interestingly enough gcc for arm is generating similar magic numbers (they look a bit less magic in hex FWIW)

Comment: IlCapitano @ Could you explain/elaborate a bit on why?

Comment: @CuriousLearner Sum of arithmetic series.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah I realized my comment was wrong :P it's probably legit very aggressive loop simplification. Amazing.

Comment: @CuriousLearner There's a formula to calculate the sum of integers from `0` to `n`, which is `n * (n-1) / 2`. Clang probably sees that the loop does exactly this, so it replaced it with the formula. The magic numbers probably have to do with the modulo calculation. If you look at the llvm IR output (with `-emit-llvm`) there're no magic numbers.

Comment: @CuriousLearner Also there's probably some extra code generated to handle cases where the multiplication overflows.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066237/fast-modulo-10-in-c

Comment: @IlCapitano you meant 0 to n - 1 or just below n ;) or n consecutive integers starting from 0

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right, I was a bit confused by the code, because it actually calculates `n * (n-1) / 2 + n` instead of `n * (n+1) / 2`.

Comment: @IlCapitano if loop boundary is `< n`, then it adds together `0` to `n - 1` whose  whose sum is `n * (n-1) / 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does call `rand`, which is sufficient. The return value will be held in the rax register. If you **divide 2³² by 1717986919 you get 2.499999999126885 which is quite close to 10 / 4... the constant is used, with shifts, to calculate the `% 10` without having to use the expensive `idiv` opcode.

After that, the result is just a sum of first n terms of arithmetic series for 1 + 2 + 3 ... + n, i.e. [n(n + 1) / 2](https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Teaching-Children-Mathematics/Blog/The-Story-of-Gauss/). The second magic number is related to this calculation.

Comment: Sorry I'm being dense. Can you explain how the `10/4` (ie., `2.5`) has any significance with `%10` ?